# Overriding virtual protected slot of QListView at runtime

Tags: python, pyqt, overriding, signals-slots, qlistview

I am using PyQt 5.9.1, and I want to connect [QListView.currentChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#currentChanged) to a function at runtime. But for some reason, I can do it only before calling `setModel()`. If I call `setModel()` (even with a `None` argument) beforehand, then my `currentChanged` function is never called.

```
# https://www.pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-qlistview-and-qstandarditemmodel/
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import  *

def currentChanged(current, previous):
    print(current, previous)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

model = QStandardItemModel()
foods = [
    'Cookie dough', # Must be store-bought
    'Hummus', # Must be homemade
    'Spaghetti', # Must be saucy
    'Dal makhani', # Must be spicy
    'Chocolate whipped cream' # Must be plentiful
]
for food in foods:
    item = QStandardItem(food)
    model.appendRow(item)

list = QListView()
list.setWindowTitle('Honey-Do List')
list.setMinimumSize(600, 400)
list.currentChanged = currentChanged  # BEFORE setModel
list.setModel(model)

list.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever `setModel()` is called, a new [selection model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html) is created. Internally, the [currentChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) signal of the new selection model is then connected to the protected [currentChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#currentChanged) slot of the list-view. Thus, whenever a data model is set, the existing internal signal connections are automatically disconnected and reconnected. In your example, when you monkey-patch `currentChanged` **after** calling `setModel()`, the internal signal connections will not be re-made, and so your function will never be called.

In general, it is usually a mistake to make changes to a view *before* setting any of its models, because there are likely to be unpredictable internal side-effects which won't always be documented.

You should also note that it is not necessary to monkey-patch `currentChanged` at all. The correct way to do things is like this:

```
list = QListView()
list.setModel(model)
list.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(currentChanged)
```

This will work in exactly the same way as your current code.

Comment: yes, i found `selectionModel().currentChanged` earlier but didn't understand internals of `QListView.currentChanged`. A selection model is initialized only once on the 1st call to `setModel()`. So it's impossible to monkey-patch this later. Thank you!